# Prevent tm from removing stopwords from double words

Tags: r, tm, corpus, stop-words

I'm trying to remove stopwords from a vector of characters. But the problem I'm facing is there is a word "king kond".Since 'king' is one of the stopwords, "king" in "king kong" is getting removed.

Is there a way to avoid double words from being removed? 
My code is:

```
text <- VCorpus(VectorSource(newmnt1$form)) 
#(newmnt1$form is  chr [1:4] "king kong lives" "foot" "island" "skull")

#Normal standardization of text.
text <- tm_map(text, content_transformer(tolower))
text <- tm_map(text, removeWords, custom_stopwords)
text <- tm_map(text, stripWhitespace)
newmnt2 <- text[[1]]$content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick hack would be to convert your "king kong" patterns to "king_kong".

```
a <- gsub("king kong", "king_kong", "This is a pattern with king and king kong")
a
[1] "This is a pattern with king and king_kong"

tm::removeWords(a, "king")
[1] "This is a pattern with  and king_kong"
```

Best,

Colin

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use another package, this works:

```
> text <- c("king kong lives", "foot", "island", "skull", "This is a pattern with king and king kong")
> corpus::term_matrix(text, drop = "king", combine = "king kong", transpose = TRUE)
11 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

a         . . . . 1
and       . . . . 1
foot      . 1 . . .
is        . . . . 1
island    . . 1 . .
king kong 1 . . . 1
lives     1 . . . .
pattern   . . . . 1
skull     . . . 1 .
this      . . . . 1
with      . . . . 1
```

The `combine` argument instructs *corpus* to interpret `king kong` as a single token.